# Why are nasty comments allowed

Tags: discussion, comments, moderation

I been here for more than a year now and dont say much but here is what I notice

I seen a few people run off and this bothered me for a while now when people can comment like this and flagging it didnt help and this is not the only thing but I was in here and remembered this and I don't expect anything to happen except nasty comments to me and being told to leave if i dont like it and getting lots of down votes or this deleted but i dont care so here it is

**Wow, when the worst thing you can complain about your mods doing is deleting comments**
[Some mod is completely out of control on this board](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6134/some-mod-is-completely-out-of-control-on-this-board#comment19490_6134)

This got six votes and i flagged it now since it wasn't deleted does this mean that the ones runnig this agree with it

The person who wrote the post also commented this

"Why am I even still here? Workplace.SE is a place that makes many people unhappy, as evidenced by the number that have left in recent times. I think it is time to join them. This is not a good way to spend my time. – user1602 May 6 at 12:49"

and then you ask questions like this.

[How can we best help brand new members who are actually putting in effort?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6272/how-can-we-best-help-brand-new-members-who-are-actually-putting-in-effort)

Why would anyone even want to try?

Comment: Clearly you're upset about some of the moderation, but right now this post just reads as a rambling vent session without a clear direction. What are you trying to achieve with this post? What sort of response would you like? I suggest that you take a step back to think about your goal and and edit your question to better reflect that.

Comment: if you flag nasty comments they will get deleted.

Comment: This answer sums up comments very well IMO https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6135/61096

Comment: Could you clarify your question?  Is this post about one declined comment flag on meta?  I think you're trying to make a broader point but I'm having trouble following; please clarify.

Comment: @MisterPositive I did flag it but I saw it again today and it's still there and it says that i already flagged it so if its still there doesnt that mean that its allowed?

Comment: @Tina_Sea - the six votes seem to indicate that individuals agree with the sentiment in the comment. That doesn't mean moderators like it or agree with it. If enough people flag the comment, it will get deleted. If you could be more specific about what bothers you, maybe we could help. Your questions have gotten a fair amount of upvotes and answers - hopefully you are getting some value here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If I can see comments are getting out of hand, what can/should I do?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4338/if-i-can-see-comments-are-getting-out-of-hand-what-can-should-i-do)

Answer (score 5):

> Why are nasty comments allowed

They're not, but apart from flagging and voting it's not your call whether something warrants deletion.

> Wow, when the worst thing you can complain about your mods doing is deleting comments

I don't see why this would warrant deletion or even flagging, so that gives you an idea of the disparity that individuals can have between their perception of what needs to be done.

> Why would anyone even want to try?

It's purely voluntary, and there is no way of knowing why an individual spends their time here. Personally I get some satisfaction from passing on experience and practicing my English in a constructive manner.